# Анимация в React router V6

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Хочу анимировать странички в своём SPA.Посмотрел ролики , поштудировал  документацию. взял пример из документации и попытался применить в своей структуре. Всё  хорошо , но есть ньюанс _ странички не рендерятся . https://disk.yandex.ru/i/HGDjUprK_gfOOA

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите ваш код, с которым возникли проблемы